# Remove Antarctica from this vega / vega-lite world map

Tags: dashboard, vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to remove Antarctica from this Vega-lite world map. Example in vega-editor [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-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-e6rcgGmrLpuPWf+x306ZrnLadp2hefUXCgBCBk+x4P8c1nWCglqaw5xvHQ-lrQyn0sIXqRZosmcVxEHulAAnwYawf+eaicDB17Xb23O7iLJhQACgAckmGol4ASnuvOs4Bw23Z8MBt755m95Bzxh6lCHDu9k5ShW9IqhHkuwDLyAMEqABrenxYmuv3p3jm78v6nlODfCEiBYo6HlpEGI5sTqwAgT7Mu9QNgo12jgNuwpmiryMJfeaFpApt1YIQMYrdCaMCSHsACDhETIhOFEQeeBqD1mNABK+0p3jcA-mQ1cNCkQomwYgW8I9waF3ButesmttroLJp7Ky+soDwMQVAmC4dG4dlMA3SO8URY3GFqPH+2I-68wzizPmgD0Cf2+OtMBcRYARFQOwbgyRoHRDKOTeAjAVqwOQesVBA0MFTywXEGaYo8ETQIbVHhepiGkKoVZbg+hPGRHibwyAtCBE4BApSNhxsKFvUnrwqAGSThVE0uaERBx2H1DUM4jGhBUlWQ0DPApkBgAAB19QViNJ0nAS8l4AGoxisFQFkTpkUIidKemATprkky9LANI9IC9hmjNmRVISUz7qdM6ZvGZElNwLKWXgFZDw1kHLQls-Zuy-iVOLshbmgSikXVNvbHemdzE51yTBS8UNbjEzecfMx-0OasNXNU2MyjGl7hKc0Tx3idBsLEVUsWhRa5S0BaYp2QDrHq1sdDZAnNEYTXCG482j4iVJzHmg6F9RglQBmgqcJ2JIl1UKTEkh6RoniQML86hxT+FlEJN86O+TaV6lhXEdgDJ4AfzuQY+R3A6mMAaU8tJzS7ZxA6V0i8Cz+lDLOWMnVlYrnrKKvM3QxzTl4BGUauZopTWQF2dsi52ZqRHO2Ms1ZdqNlusdTc+VtoHniuxDHIw-8gVO25iKvcfLnlhsxdnfOgawAQsOoSiefy5wd1afq714zWqTKTimtNygGG2xDXySVBYLSPkqCW5FxdARKFfs8GQRNrBqocOgTmjBYAAE1xVv0sAAUSJbWscnhm22hAACIAA). Wondering how I can get hold of specific data w.r.t country or continent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter transnform:

```js
 {
  "name": "world", // <---- Your map
  "url": "https://vega.github.io/editor/data/world-110m.json",
  "format": {
    "type": "topojson",
    "feature": "countries"
  },
  "transform": [ 
    {      
      "type": "filter",
      "expr":"datum.id!=10" //<---- Antarctica has id 10
    }
  ]
},
```

[See on your example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-gOgYzqxY7sWBEEsVBcQAJIAHLwcGLyruuUDCTIFj7jCOEHHh1aymAcyePKdCKqImqXl+j62NpRaeAxlYscBPr9mANiDtO3FWXx-qAYJ3Chs0ADCYYSbOUlIXEnkgoYik3MphSqQ4BFgEWJr1lqFpasxM6UU+YAMY2niiO4SVAT+1m6PK9l5Wxf5gW6DlBvE7knAAUgACr5UCIWuzS1eg+hyNhVaRQ+6lGqaip0RqiqGVRNgNi+XjliVvF-jZRWuSlPEgb6AFcVVQlQPOADSTXVXGrVxPOKGogYYA7ZY1AGF6PwHuKDKFMpx6QGyJyOtyLq6t+XInJylQ8ny33AqC4KQtkma9XCCJxCmFwrPtSKJAY3zZNKVzyKlkB0kBATFMkcQ1hEaKfdyRMk543Jw5cMi8ndSk9SxRwnHD5yWLsX54hcyDwHgPAFnolTc7z-OI58NSo2AWTo6sWM4yx6CS9L5OVKTKu8ty2IKJRxOq7MZPoLrGsJo9SkPYyawvW9zQfX633-QkHIvAD3ZA+Kpw7qD2xijmTPwizyDwxjLFIxLUIy9r+q7PLy0aNQ+PNOr+tJ1Tgc03T3WQ37MNQKz3Ds-tXMSDzfPqaYQvFyLwfLaHKPh6emNR9jX6K-Xhsk8n7d65rkcpynJvYebT1KDHgvC6XoI+xK7vW3ERcl6L9taGUqlhHjQrNFkziuIgmMoAE+B0vTT3fUiaWr3HCdxFkjoABQAOSTDU98AJSY33Xca9TKy8u-n+d0bfW39ZC8iPuKcKUBmbNFKADdIVRj5ZhHqEDAlQADWStmQzxKCcdWlMUHoKXNDP6iAOo6HtpEGI4c4awBIQiUe9QNhC3BmAVejpmhPyMOA76qYtqr1YIQMYK8Q7IgJiwiiDhBTChwQfPA1AdwJgohA207xuCoKESlCRQoRTsMQKhBBYUKKNzUNwFEjBCB7HEVAWu2BIAuH0QcGk90wrA09mCb2ENfbLSgbDQONDSGFwrgvMu88q5dScQcU2EBnpYPZITf+BsjZ4PQGg74wN-YcgiKgdgJjCHhGiGUaW8BGAA0ofQ9YjDbo4FYb2G2vZPr2IgViGQvDMwNAEekdR3FuD6CKZECxGioCSO0TgGiGpFFfiREkfpGjIBDJOFUEEKZ7EnyZtwExfNzFVMsWveOG84jAAADoHWkkcnA9974AGoiSoCyEclqEQjk4zAEcpy81TlgDBukW+1zbkrWso8zGRyjlv2eX8vi7zPl4G+Q8G5Lz8rgubqC4Ffxln-C-FrLZAzNjiyMHEwBCSKY93GSxGSvVbg4sTvE3B3IFEpSUesPxOcyWDK0U8Yp8BKGKMHgYlZEUYk4KpfE-BqT3beMgTiDm7s8mULRqibE0dT5MOmZiNhcRbYNO4c0mqyq9T8METqlVpLtlzMNPKYlNcREGqlCauI7AazwFQaiqJX5jGmM2WIrFl89lQEOcc+M7zzlXJhb8+5ALQWvL7BC7YXyflwtKpGxFQLIAgrjXNUCUaIQxuDam1aWow1Jpfii813EMUepmdYvFHcCXdy1sWqqRqsUVp1lW-uTqswuolVazEXrRGQEDbGv1a5HltvpQ4Xc8cu16htc1VMqJ0RcvCcPJdYBR7VRkEiawmL1joGxIwWAABNK1kBUCWAAKLytnboRUnhGRKBpDSIAA)